# Debian package exact specific version depends

Tags: dependencies, debian, version, apt

I'm trying to make a debian package A (kind of meta-package), that doesnt have content but only dependencies. But I want it have *exact version* dependencies.

That is this control file:

```
Package: ax-pipeline-prod
Version: 20210209
Architecture: all
Depends: ax-pipeline (= 0.6.0.135)
Maintainer: gregory.starck@algolux.com
Description: description
```

But when I install the package produced by the above *control* body, I get following error:

```
15:29 $ sudo apt-get install  ./ax-pipeline-prod-20210211-1.0.deb 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'ax-pipeline-prod' instead of './ax-pipeline-prod-20210211-1.0.deb'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ax-pipeline-prod : Depends: ax-pipeline (= 0.6.0.135) but 0.6.0.136 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

there is effectively an *ax-pipeline* package at version 0.6.0.136 (but there is also the  one I desire 0.6.0.135).

My question is why APT *simply* doesnt download & install the version I explicitly depends on (ie 0.6.0.135) and instead produces the above error. Which is a bit missleading because I dont have any held broken packages.. btw.

Any APT/debian expert ?

otherwise I know I can effectively install the requested package at the desired version but I have to explictly do it on command line :

```
apt-get install ax-pipeline=0.6.0.135
```

and we *could* be happy. but **no** I **want** that to be in my *ax-pipeline-prod* package actually.

Thx for any information (and please tell me this is possible?).

Answer (score 1):

Answer to myself:

This is actually feasable. By putting the version in the package name and using a virtual package.